# Loopback 4 Cronjob , repository not bound

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

I use cronjob that described in document and i whould use repository in job but below error occured
this is my `CronJobComponent`:

```js
import {CronJob, cronJob} from '@loopback/cron';
import {repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import moment from 'moment';

import {SettingsRepository, UsersRepository} from '../repositories';

@cronJob()
export class CronJobComponent extends CronJob {
  constructor(
    @repository(UsersRepository) public usersRepository: UsersRepository,
    @repository(SettingsRepository)
    public settingsRepository: SettingsRepository,
  ) {
    super({
      name: 'job-1',
      cronTime: '* */1 * * * *',
      onTick: async () => {
        await this.scheduleNotifyJob();
      },
      start: false,
    });
  }

  async scheduleNotifyJob() {
    const foundUserIds = await this.settingsRepository.find({
      fields: {userId: true},
      where: {
        scheduleNotify: true,
        scheduleTime: moment().startOf('minute').toString(),
      },
    });

    console.log(foundUserIds);
  }
}
```

This is my *Application.ts* file

```js
export class MyApplication extends BootMixin(
      ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
    ) {
    
      constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {

        this.component(CronJobComponent);
        this.add(createBindingFromClass(CronJobComponent));

    }
}
```

**Current Behavior**

This is output that mentioning:

> The key 'repositories.SettingsRepository' is not bound to any value in context

```json
  Cannot start the application. ResolutionError: The key 'repositories.SettingsRepository' is not bound to any value in context MyApplication-4yxpOGOFSwS3Y68UCUEVGA-0 (context: MyApplication-4yxpOGOFSwS3Y68UCUEVGA-0, binding: repositories.SettingsRepository, resolutionPath: components.CronJobComponent --> @CronJobComponent.constructor[0])
  
  {
  resolutionCtx: {
    context: MyApplication {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: Infinity,
      registry: [Map],
      _parent: undefined,
      name: 'MyApplication-4yxpOGOFSwS3Y68UCUEVGA-0',
      tagIndexer: [ContextTagIndexer],
      subscriptionManager: [ContextSubscriptionManager],
      _debug: [Function],
      _isShuttingDown: false,
      _state: 'created',
      options: [Object],
      _shutdownOptions: [Object],
      hashRound: 10,
      configResolver: [DefaultConfigurationResolver],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    binding: Binding {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      isLocked: false,
      tagMap: {},
      key: 'repositories.SettingsRepository',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    options: {
      session: [ResolutionSession],
      decorator: '@inject',
      name: 'SettingsRepository',
      modelName: undefined,
      modelClass: undefined,
      dataSourceName: undefined,
      dataSource: undefined
    }
  },
  name: 'ResolutionError'
}
```

Additional information about my environment:

```
    linux x64 13.13.0

    ├── @loopback/authentication@4.2.10
    ├── @loopback/authorization@0.6.3
    ├── @loopback/boot@2.4.0
    ├── @loopback/cli@2.11.0
    ├── @loopback/context@3.9.3
    ├── @loopback/core@2.9.2
    ├── @loopback/cron@0.2.10
    ├── @loopback/express@1.2.6
    ├── @loopback/extension-health@0.4.10
    ├── @loopback/extension-metrics@0.3.10
    ├── @loopback/openapi-v3@3.4.6
    ├── @loopback/repository@2.10.0
    ├── @loopback/rest@5.2.1
    ├── @loopback/rest-explorer@2.2.7
    ├── @loopback/service-proxy@2.3.5
    ├── loopback-connector-mysql@5.4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like an import issue.
In your `application.ts`, try importing the following:

```
import {CronJobComponent} from './cronJobComponent'; // <- Your component
import {CronComponent} from '@loopback/cron';
```

after that in the same file put this in your constructor:

```
this.component(CronComponent);
this.add(createBindingFromClass(CronJobComponent));
```